# Can't escape the State Monad

Tags: haskell

I'm using the State Monad to maintain my world, and am using Gloss for graphics. Gloss passes a "world" object between each "tick" to continue it forwards. The problem is, for this to work I need to be able to define:

```
wsToPicture :: WorldState () -> Picture
```

where

```
World = data World = World { ... }
WorldState = type WorldState = State World
Picture = Gloss's representation of a graphic.
```

The best I could get is:

```
wsToPicture :: WorldState () -> Picture
wsToPicture ws = toPicture . execState ws startingWorld
```

where

```
startingWorld = The very initial state of the world
toPicture = World -> Picture (Defined elsewhere)
```

Which at least compiles, but the world resets every tick. Putting `startingWorld` in there was purely get it to compile; I know it's wrong. How do I get out of the `State` monad if I don't have a current `World` to give it? The only World available is inside the `WorldState`, and I can't use `get` to extract it, because as soon as I use `>>=`, the function has to return a `WorldState`.

I'm assuming that I'm misunderstanding something. Can someone shed some light on what that might be?

Comment: Have you tried `wsToPicture :: WorldState Picture`; `wsToPicture = fmap toPicture get`, then you can keep everything in the state monad instead of trying to escape it.

Comment: An alternate definition would be `wsToPicture = do { ws <- get; return $ toPicture ws }`

Comment: @bheklilr: gloss expects `world -> Picture` IIRC.

Comment: @Zeta hmmm, didn't know that.  Sounds like an odd API then.  Does it not have a monad transformer or something?

Comment: When you use `gloss`, it shouldn't be necessary to use the State monad at all. After all, your state _is_ the world. If you used `State` just for `get` and `set`, have a look at the lens library, it might suit you.

Comment: @bheklilr: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.8.2.2/docs/Graphics-Gloss.html#v:play. Its interface is heavily influenced by the handle-update-draw-loop in imperative game programming, afaik. There's not really much space for monads there, although it's possible.

Comment: @bheklilr You can't stay in the Monad, as , as @Zeta pointed out, Gloss expects a non-monadic representation of the `Picture`; it won't unwrap the value for you. You can use `IO`, but for some reason, they limited it to `IO`, not a more generic `m a`. I decided to try using `State` because it seemed magical, but maybe this isn't the time and place.

Comment: @bheklilr And there's another vote for the `lens` library that you suggested. Maybe I will give it a whirl. Thanks guys.

Comment: If you're like me coming from Google and looking for a function `State s a -> s -> a`, then that's [evalState](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:evalState)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Gloss carries already a state for you, it's the world given to your update and event handling function:

```
update :: TimeDiff -> World -> World
handle :: Event    -> World -> World
--                    |||||    ^^^^^ next world
--                    ^^^^^ current world
```

You probably used `State` for simple modification of your world. That's entirely possible **in** `update` or `handle`:

```
update :: TimeDiff -> World -> World
update dt world = flip execstate world $ do
    -- do something with world, e.g.
    modify (\w -> w {players = round (exp dt) })
```

But your `World` itself shouldn't be based on `State`  or `StateT`.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually how I had it set up originally, but it seemed bulky having to leave the monad on existing a handler, only to re-enter it at the start of the next handler. I thought staying in it would clean it up, but apparently not. Both you and bheklilr suggested lens, so I'll look at it next. Thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: The lens library might seem a little bit overwhelming at first. Have a look at the video by Edward Kmett or the blog posts at fpcomplete.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably just go off on a tangent and start a new project that models the ideal use case. I read that someone used lenses to model a house automation system that was represented by a deeply nested object. Maybe I'll give that a go.